# Grub will only boot one of my two windows OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am perplexed with Grub and am hoping someone can advise me.  I have three operating systems installed on my computer: Linuxmint 17 and Windows 7 on sda, and windows Vista on sdb.  I updated grub and all three are found and added to the menu.  However only Windows 7 boots when I pick Windows Vista.  Windows 7 boots when I pick Windows 7, but I cannot get Vista to boot from sba.  I tried updating with grub customizer but that did not help.  I installed and ran Boot Repair which suggested installing grub on each drive which I did. it did not change anything on sba, but when I changed the drive priority in the BIOS to make sdb first I can now boot Vista, but when I pick windows 7 it boots vista! Linuxmint boots fine in ether situation.  I'm guessing that grub is probably just looking for a Windows Operating System When I choose Windows & or Vista and grabs whichever is on that particular drive.  ANy way I can fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Not really a grub issue. Windows normally installs to only one drive'sMBR that is set to boot from BIOS, then all boot files for all installs are in the one primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. Or without lots of details on Windows configuration, it cannot be easily fixed. This is an Ubuntu forum, so you may be moved or told to post in StackExchange general area. You may be able to just set BIOS to correct drive and set boot flag to correct Windows and run that versions repairs to restore only its boot files. Do for all Windows installs. Then each install has its own boot files for grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two Ubuntu versions on my system.  Sometimes grub will boot into one, other times the other.  To be sure of what I'm booting I use a SuperGrub cd.  It boots and offers a menu, the first item is "find all OS's on the system."  I then get to choose which one to boot.  This may not be a "solution" but it is a pretty good work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Install Boot-repair and repair your grub

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I already tried that.  It does not change anything.